# Is it possible to detect if a writer is tty or not?

Tags: go, colors, console, tty

Bash has a 'magical behavior', if you type 'ls', usually you will get colorful output, but if you redirect the output to a file, the color codes are gone.  How to achive this effect using Go.  e.g. With the following statement:

```
fmt.Println("\033[1;34mHello World!\033[0m")
```

I can see the text in color, but if I pipe the output to a file, the color is *preserved*, which is **NOT** what I want.

BTW, this question is mostly *not* related to Go, I just want to achive the effect in my go program.

Comment: [This seems to be the most popular package for implementing `isatty`.](https://github.com/mattn/go-isatty) There are a few others that I have come across.

Comment: It is possible on some OSes. [Logrus](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus) has support for this for various OSes in the various `terminal_check*` files.

Comment: `Bash has a 'magical behavior', if you type 'ls', usually you will get colorful output, but if you redirect the output to a file, the color codes are gone.` - this is ls feature, not Bash

Comment: The accepted answer isn't great -- @ptx comment is the most portable answer: "A better approach is to use term.IsTerminal from x/term"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Bash has a 'magical behavior', if you type 'ls', usually you will
> get colorful output, but if you redirect the output to a file, the
> color codes are gone.

It's not Bash feature, it's ls feature. It calls
[isatty()](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/isatty.html)
to check if stdout file descriptor refers to a terminal. In musl libc
isatty is implemented like that:

```
int isatty(int fd)
{
        struct winsize wsz;
        unsigned long r = syscall(SYS_ioctl, fd, TIOCGWINSZ, &wsz);
        if (r == 0) return 1;
        if (errno != EBADF) errno = ENOTTY;
        return 0;
}
```

You can use the same method in Go:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "os"

        "golang.org/x/sys/unix"
)

func main() {
        _, err := unix.IoctlGetWinsize(int(os.Stdout.Fd()), unix.TIOCGWINSZ)
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Hello World")
        } else {
                fmt.Println("\033[1;34mHello World!\033[0m")
        }
}
```

Comment: This actually works. However, my code is: `func Dump(w io.Writer) { ... }`, so, I can simply use your code, plus a wrapper: if w == os.Stdout { ... }

Comment: one more question:  does this work on Windows? https://github.com/mattn/go-isatty has a function called `IsCygwinTerminal()`, this means tty-color is a feature of *nix system (or windows with an emulator)?

Comment: I don't know, I don't use Windows

Comment: A better approach is to use `term.IsTerminal` from [x/term](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/term#IsTerminal). It works on windows and is maintained by the golang team

Comment: Note that you actually need to use`term.IsTerminal(int(os.Stdout.Fd()))`, for a complete and usable answer

Answer (score 9):

I'm just answering by copying @ptx comment, which is the more canonical answer:

> A better approach is to use term.IsTerminal from [x/term](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/term#IsTerminal). It works on windows and is maintained by the golang team

This is to raise visibility, as this answer is portable and doesn't add an external dependency.

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "golang.org/x/term"
)

func main() {
    if term.IsTerminal(int(os.Stdout.Fd())) {
        // do stuff when we are attached to a tty
    } else {
        // do stuff when we are not attached
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just viewing a log file and don't want colors being preserved because it makes logs less readable, note that

```
less -r logfile
more -r logfile
multitail -cT ANSI logfile
```

will make these commands display ANSI colors.

There is also a vim plugin which does the same: https://github.com/powerman/vim-plugin-AnsiEsc

For some use cases this could be a simpler solution than upgrading an app to detect whether an output is attached to a tty.