# How check whether a program is running the terminal or in the background?

Tags: linux, go, terminal, stdout

Hi I am working a go program which gives some output in two ways depending on the execution:

- It outputs to **stdout** if it is **executed in the terminal**
- It is paired with a keyboard shortcut (eg. CTRL+M) in which it sends the **output as notification** if its **invoked via keyboard shortcut**.

Now i want to **determine** whether the **program is running in the terminal or not** to decide the mode of output... is there any way in linux to determine this condition?

Currently the program is outputting in both stdout and notification, I wanted to only send the output via notification when it is invoked via keyboard shortcut. because printing to stdout when it is not running in the terminal is simply useless.

Comment: Take a look at this : https://rderik.com/blog/identify-if-output-goes-to-the-terminal-or-is-being-redirected-in-golang/

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this method works really well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume that when it's invoked via keyboard shortcut it is run by your desktop environment in some way and the output won't be a terminal, so you could check [whether stdout is a tty or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68889637/is-it-possible-to-detect-if-a-writer-is-tty-or-not). Based on [Arkadiusz Drabczyk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68890046/1871033), you could use this code:

```golang
package main

import (
        "os"
        "golang.org/x/sys/unix"
)

func main() {
        _, err := unix.IoctlGetWinsize(int(os.Stdout.Fd()), unix.TIOCGWINSZ)
        if err != nil {
                // Show notification here
        } else {
                // Print to stdout here
        }
}
```

**Note that this would also cause it to use a notification instead of stdout when it's redirected with `|` or `>`, though.** If that's not good, you would have to use an explicit command line argument instead - I personally would prefer this anyway, because it clearly communicates intent and won't have surprises. You could accept an argument `--notification` which you add to the keyboard shortcut but don't use when invoking the tool in the command line.

If for some reason it is inconvenient to add an argument, you could also use a symlink with a different name and check `os.Args[0]`. So for example, if your program is `~/bin/hello`, then you'd create a "second version" called `~/bin/hello-notify` which is actually just a symlink to `~/bin/hello`, but in your code you check wither your `os.Args[0]` ends with `-notify`. Then you can connect the keyboard shortcut to `~/bin/hello-notify` but use `~/bin/hello` in the command line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer It works as intended. But, this blog [link] (https://rderik.com/blog/identify-if-output-goes-to-the-terminal-or-is-being-redirected-in-golang/) mentioned by @Philippe does the trick only  using the built-in os package.